# Can the equation between apparent brightness and luminosity be applied to lux and lumens?

Tags: experimental-physics, luminosity

The equation

$b=L/4πd^2$

(where $b$ is apparent brightness in $W/m^2$, $L$ is luminosity, $d$ is distance to a star (or in this case to a torch)).

I'm completing an experiment, but I can't find a measurement app for $W/m^2$. Since lux is equal to lumens per area, cwould the equation be valid if I change $b$ to lux and $L$ to lumens?